# ¿Como paso una consulta insert de input multiples con el mismo nombre de php a codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta insert en php y quiero pasarlo a codeigniter 4, es de un formulario que recibe varios valores de campos input con el mismo nombre del tipo  `<input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_1" class="form-control">`, pero me cuesta pasarlo en codeigniter por el for para que ingrese uno por uno en la base de datos.
Asi esta en php.

```
    $lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($this->dbConnect);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($POST['productCode']); $i++) {
        $sqlInsertItem = "
        INSERT INTO ".$this->invoiceOrderItemTable."(order_id, item_code, item_name, order_item_quantity, order_item_price, order_item_final_amount) 
        VALUES ('".$lastInsertId."', '".$POST['productCode'][$i]."', '".$POST['productName'][$i]."', '".$POST['quantity'][$i]."', '".$POST['price'][$i]."', '".$POST['total'][$i]."')";         
        mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlInsertItem);
    }
```

Los datos no los envío con ajax.

Comment: Mejor que pongas la respuesta en una respuesta, y no en la pregunta, sino esta quedará siempre abierta pendiente de responder. Luego, al cabo de 12 horas creo que es, puedes aceptar tu misma respuesta y así cerramos el ciclo correcto de las preguntas con respuestas aceptadas, gracias.

Comment: listo, muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias a ti por contribuir en el buen funcionamiento del sitio :-) Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo, no se si a alguien le sirva pero lo dejo por aquí, no se si esta bien pero me inserta los registros bien.

```
$ultimoId = $this->invoiceOrderTable->insertID('order_id');

$post = $this->request->getPost();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($post['productCode']); $i++) 
            {
            $data=array('order_id' => $ultimoId,
                        'item_code' => $post['productCode'][$i],
                        'item_name' => $post['productName'][$i],
          'order_item_quantity' => $post['quantity'][$i],
          'order_item_price' => $post['price'][$i],
          'order_item_final_amount' => $post['total'][$i],);
                
            $this->invoiceOrderItemTable->insert($data);

            }
```